# Problem terminating my app with an exit code

Tags: android

After my app runs and completes its work, I want it to terminate and return an exit code back to the operating system. This can be done using:

```
System.exit(exitCode)
```

The only problem with this is that Android will then attempt to restart the app again after it terminates it. I want to avoid this. The reason I want to terminate the app with an exit code is to allow for continuous integration testing which will allow external apps to determine whether the app succeeded or failed.

How can I terminate the app with an exit code but prevent it from restarting?

Answer (score 1):

How can I terminate the app with an exit code but prevent it from restarting?

You can try with [**`finishAndRemoveTask()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask.html#finishAndRemoveTask()).
Added in API level 21

> Finishes all activities in this task and removes it from the recent
>   tasks list.

For API Level 19, You can use [**`finishAffinity()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity())

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in
>   the current task that have the same affinity. This is typically used
>   when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from
>   an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used
>   the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own
>   task. In this case, if the user has navigated down into any other
>   activities of the second application, all of those should be removed
>   from the original task as part of the task switch.

Another Simple way

```
Intent intOBJ = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intOBJ.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
intOBJ.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
startActivity(intOBJ);
```

Comment: Requires API 21+. I'm using API 19.

Comment: @AndroidDev then try with finishAffinity()

Comment: @AndroidDev, if below 21 `finishAffinity();` else `finishAndRemoveTask();` or `finishAndRemoveTask()`

Comment: finishAffinity doesn't prevent Android from restarting the activity. finishAndRemoveTask requires API 21.

Comment: @AndroidDev check version `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) { } else{}`. check edited answer.